# Failure to display result of an option, radio and number value input combination

Tags: javascript, html

My problem may exist in the insurance radio buttons, and interpreting their values into the calculate() function. My goal is to take the value of each option item, (Compact=$30 a day, Intermediate=$40 a day, Standard=$50 a day) multiply those values to the number of days the car was rented, and factor in whether or not the customer purchased insurance on the given vehicle (insurance=+$15 a day, no insurance=+$0 a day) I am having trouble coding the function correctly to what I need.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function calculate() {
   var carType = document.getElementById('selectCar').value;
   var days = document.getElementById('daysRenting').value;
   var yInsurance = document.getElementById('yesInsurance');
   var nInsurance = document.getElementById('noInsurance');
   var result = (carType * days * yInsurance * nInsurance);
   totalCost.value= result;
   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div align="center">
      <form name="carForm">
         <p>
            <strong>
         <h1>Car Rental Service</h1></strong></p>
         <hr>
         <select name='selectCar' onchange="calculate(this.value)">
            <option value="0">Pick A Car Type</option>
            <option value="30" id='compact'>Compact</option>
            <option value="40" id='intermediate'>Intermediate</option>
            <option value="50" id='standard'>Standard</option>
         </select>
         <hr>
         <input type="text" id="daysRenting" size="41px" placeholder="How many days are you renting this vehicle?"/>
         <hr>
         I want insurance on this vehicle.<input type="radio" value='15' name='insurance' id="yesInsurance"><br>
         I do not want insurance on this vehicle.<input type="radio" value='0' name='insurance' id="noInsurance">
         <hr>
         <input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="Click here to process request"><br><br>
         Total Cost to Rent: <input type="number" id='total' name='totalCost' size=8 readonly><br><br>
         <input type="reset" value="Reset"><br>
         <hr>
      </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: What specifically is not working? Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in the console, just the failure to display the result of the calculated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of errors:

- there is no ID `selectCar` in `var carType = document.getElementById('selectCar').value;`
- `totalCost` not defined (`var totalCost = document.getElementById('total');`)
- wrong multiplications in `var result = (carType * days * yInsurance * nInsurance);` because `nInsurance` and `yInsurance` refer to the DOM elements, not their values, so they can't be multiplied
- even if they refered to values, one of them is always zero, making the `result` always 0

---

Here's a fixed version:

```js
function calculate() {
  var carType = document.getElementById('selectCar').value;
  var days = document.getElementById('daysRenting').value;
  var yInsurance = document.getElementById('yesInsurance');
  var nInsurance = document.getElementById('noInsurance');
  var result = (carType * days);
  if (yInsurance.checked) 
    result += parseInt(yInsurance.value, 10) * days;
  var totalCost = document.getElementById('total');
  totalCost.value = result;
}
```

```html
<div align="center"><form name="carForm">
<p><strong><h1>Car Rental Service</h1></strong></p><hr>
<select name='selectCar' onchange="calculate(this.value)" id="selectCar">
<option value="0">Pick A Car Type</option>
<option value="30" id='compact'>Compact</option>
<option value="40" id='intermediate'>Intermediate</option>
<option value="50" id='standard'>Standard</option>
</select><hr>
<input type="text" id="daysRenting" size="41px" placeholder="How many days are you renting this vehicle?"/><hr>
I want insurance on this vehicle.<input type="radio" value='15' name='insurance' id="yesInsurance"><br>
I do not want insurance on this vehicle.<input type="radio" value='0' name='insurance' id="noInsurance"><hr>
<input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="Click here to process request"><br><br>
Total Cost to Rent: <input type="number" id='total' name='totalCost' size=8 readonly><br><br>
<input type="reset" value="Reset"><br><hr>
</form></div>
```

Comment: How would I edit the yInsurance and nInsurance variables so they refer to the DOM elements, instead of their values?

Comment: They should actually refer to the elements, as you originally did, but you cannot multiply them as elements, but need their value instead. I've written you the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you don't have an element with the ID `selectCar` - you have element with such name, which is not the same.